# Monitor batch job by Prometheus

Tags: python, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

There is a Python batch job that pushes huge file(s) to a shared location, once the file(s) are pushed, couple of tests will be run against that/those file(s).
I'm trying to get some metrics around the batch job & planning to use Node exporter having below metrics or labels.

```
file_push_status (success or failure)
first_test_status (Pass or Fail)
second_test_status (Pass or Fail)
first_test_time_taken (How long)
second_test_time_taken (How long)
```

Gone thru prometheus documentation, but unable to get a clarity whether Summary or Histogram should be used here ? I understand, Prometheus doesnt support Boolean(1st 3 cases), how those should be handled ?

If needed will attach the existing batch job code, thank you.

Comment: How many files would be processed? Will they have the same name from job to job?

Comment: @markalex:  Simplicity sake, lets say one file and a single job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small number of files you don't need histograms.

Make all three metrics gauges.

Something like

```
# HELP file_push_success A metric with 0/1 value showing result of file push job. 0 - failure.
# TYPE file_push_success gauge
file_push_success{file="filename.txt"} 1 

# HELP file_push_test_success A metric with 0/1 value showing result of corresponding test after file being pushed. 0 - failure.
# TYPE file_push_test_success gauge
file_push_test_success{file="filename.txt", test="1"} 1
file_push_test_success{file="filename.txt", test="2"} 0

# HELP file_push_test_duration_seconds Duration of corresponding test after file being pushed 
# TYPE file_push_test_duration_seconds gauge
file_push_test_duration_seconds{file="filename.txt", test="1"} 5
file_push_test_duration_seconds{file="filename.txt", test="2"} 13
```

Here I grouped related metrics into one with different labels. It would be more easier to support (for example when you'll decide to add new tests), and is generally advised by Prometheus [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/).

Comment: That's cool, thank you.
I can make use of the above suggested gauges using `prometheus_client` Python library as well right ?

Comment: @ChelMS, of course. [Here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#gauge) is example.

Comment: Awesome ! Will try that out..